# Delegate methods for typing indicator on Twilio chat not being called

Tags: ios, swift, twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

Working on a Swift chat application.
On one device, I join a channel with unique name `"private:chat"`, and then I call `channel.typing()` on the channel (as is mention in [docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/typing-indicator)).
On another device, I again create a client with a `delegate` set to `self`:

```
TwilioChatClient.chatClient(withToken: token, properties: nil, delegate: self) { (result, chatClient) in
    self.client = chatClient
}
```

And then I implemented `typingStartedOn` delegate method to listen to typing on the channel.

```
func chatClient(_ client: TwilioChatClient, typingStartedOn channel: TCHChannel, member: TCHMember) {
    print(">>>>>>>>>>>>> typing on \(channel.uniqueName) by \(member.identity)")
}
```

However, the delegate method does not get called, even though I confirmed that the `channel.typing()` gets called by the other account on the other device. The [docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/typing-indicator) inline code in JS, but based on [iOS chat demo app](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-chat-demo-ios) I came to conclusion that in Swift the delegate methods are the way to go.

Any idea what might be going on here?

EDIT: Some (haven't tested all) of the other delegate methods, such as `synchronizationStatusUpdated`, are getting called.

Comment: Can you share the code you are using to start the typing indicator for the channel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after all, the issue was not in the iOS client, but in our implementation of the access token server.

As @rbeiter noted in his [comment on GitHub issue](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-chat-demo-ios/issues/42), Twilio does not send typing indicator if the user identity is the same on both devices. I was setting the identity properly on both devices to keep it different, but our access token server ignored the identity parameter and used a hardcoded value. Thus from Twilio viewpoint, the same user was on both devices. Fixing the access token server fixed the problem.